# SQL SERVER 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

how to update database structure using script?

I have old db in one server and new db in another server, I have to update the old db structure with new one. Can we do using script?

Please any one help me

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

There are really great tools that do this. [Sql Compare from Red Gate](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Compare/index.htm) is excellent and I've used it often to do this kind of thing.

> SQL Compare is the industry-standard
>   tool for comparing and synchronizing
>   SQL Server database schemas. It's used
>   by over 200,000 developers, DBAs and
>   test engineers worldwide because it's
>   easy to use, it's fast, and it saves
>   time.
>
> Whether you are working with live
>   databases, database snapshots, object
>   SQL scripts under source control or an
>   earlier backup, SQL Compare will help
>   you compare and synchronize database
>   changes quickly, simply and with zero
>   errors.
>
> Read the whitepaper on database
>   development and discover how SQL
>   Compare can save you astonishing
>   amounts of time, whatever development
>   model your team prefers to use. SQL
>   Compare ensures accurate, fast results
>   with maximum end-user

Comment: I agree. I've used both Red-Gate SQL Compare and another product called SQL Examiner... Red-Gate SQL Compare is an excellent tool

Comment: PS. I'm not on commission but a very happy customer.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need some sort of structure comparison tool.

There are many on the market (none built-in), my personal favorite is SQL Delta:

http://www.sqldelta.com/

It enables both Structure comparison (and update scripting) and data comparison and scripting, with both possible from the command-line. (and it's quite cheap).